# nodejs How to scraping multi site in scraping loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, cheerio

I'm trying to make simple feed reader in node and I'm facing a problem with multiple requests in node.js. For example,
i got this code :

```
var url = [
    "https://site1.com",
    "https://site2.com"
]; 
var items = [];
var i;
for(i=0; i<url.length; i++){
    request(url[i], function(err, respone, html){
    if(!err) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        if(i == 0){
            $(".class1").find("a").each(function (index, element){
                items.push($(element).text());
            });
        }else if(i == 1){
            $(".class1").find("a").each(function (index, element){
                items.push($(element).text());
            });
        }
    }
    });
}
```

How to scraping multi site in scraping loop ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) with [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) in this case, since network requests can be asynchronous.

```js
var urls = [
    "https://site1.com",
    "https://site2.com"
]; 
var promises = [];
   
for(var url of urls) {
  promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    request(url, function(err, respone, html){
        if(err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var items = [];
        $(".class1").find("a").each(function (index, element){
          items.push($(element).text());
        });
        return resolve(items);
    });
  })
}

Promise.all(promises).then((results)=>{
  console.log(results);
}).catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error);
});
```